# Why is the behavior of the typescript different when declaring variables?

Tags: typescript, types

Why is the behavior of the typescript different when declaring variables?

```
let a = "asdasd"; // here type is string
const b = "asdads"; // here type is "asdads". Why not string? if i try assign this as type for another variable it must be initializing with this value

const something = { // here type is {a:"something"}
    a:"something"
}
let somethingg = { // here type is also as above. But must be object
    a:"something"
}
```

Comment: let values can be reassigned so let a might not always be equal to "asdasd" whereas const b cannot be reassigned to something else

Answer (score 3):

## `let`

You declare a variable using `let`

```
let a = 'hello';
```

Typescript can infer:

1. ✅ The variable's declaration → (type becomes `any`)
2. ✅ The variable's type → (type becomes `string`)
3. ❌ The variable's content → ?

This is because you may change the value of the variable elsewhere in code:

```
let a = 'hello';

a = 'bye';
```

## `const`

You declare a variable using `const`

```
const a = 'hello';
```

Typescript can infer:

1. ✅ The variable's declaration → (type becomes `any`)
2. ✅ The variable's type → (type becomes `string`)
3. ✅ The variable's content → (type becomes `'hello'`)

This is because you may **not** change the value of the variable elsewhere in code:

```
const a = 'hello';

a = 'bye'; // Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```